# Responsive img mapping jQuery plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I am trying to have links on a image so I mapped it and I am using this plugin to have it responsive http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html

I am loading at the bottom jQuery, then the plugin script and the passing the function.

Everything should be fine, but it doesn't work properly. Anyone can give me a hint?

http://test30.hscreativedev.co.uk/web/web/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple mistake: you didn't copy&paste all the plugins code. Last line of script in your HTML file is:

```
    return this;
  };
});
```

While it [should be](https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps/blob/master/jquery.rwdImageMaps.js):

```
    return this;
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: thank you! I am still a beginner so sometimes when I copy and paste I don't always understand .js.